# Tensorflow 2.1 image classification with custom channel manipulations

Tags: python, classification, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying to create a series of hand crafted channels that are part of the graph that I would like to stack onto the input image/tensor before it is run through the rest of the network.

```py
input_tensor = KL.Input(shape=input_image, name="input")
handcrafted_channels = handcrafted(input_tensor)
x = KL.concatenate([input_tensor, handcrafted_channels], axis=-1)
x = KL.ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(x)
x = KL.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1), strides=(1,1), padding="same")(x)
x = KL.Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), name='conv1', use_bias=True, input_shape=x.shape, data_format="channels_last")(x)
... continue with normal resnet

def handcrafted(self, input_tensor):
    _red, _green, _blue = tf.split(input_tensor, 3, axis = 3)
    # This could be any sort of equation, but for example a really simple set
    handcrafted_channel_a = KL.add([_red, _green])
    handcrafted_channel_b = KL.subtract([_green, _blue])
    handcrafted_channels = KL.concatenate([handcrafted_channel_a, handcrafted_channel_b], axis=-1)
    return handcrafted_channels
```

When ever I run this with a loss function of sparse_categorical_crossentropy and an optimizer of SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, clipnorm=5.0) I get nan for the loss. To ensure that the rest of the network is fine, I can successfully run the training if I remove the handcrafted_channels and don't have the first concatenate.

[Training run with handcrafted enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GLbX.png)

[Training run without handcrafted enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZktb.png)

And the error message that is dumped out at the end of the 1st epoch:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-77a19ea1ade6> in <module>
     48           reduce_lr,
---> 49           early_stopping,
     50         ])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    817         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    818         workers=workers,
--> 819         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    820 
    821   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    395                       total_epochs=1)
    396                   cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, eval_result, ModeKeys.TEST,
--> 397                                  prefix='val_')
    398 
    399     return model.history

/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     86         if type is None:
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:
     90                 return False

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in on_epoch(self, epoch, mode)
    769       if mode == ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    770         # Epochs only apply to `fit`.
--> 771         self.callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    772       self.progbar.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
    773 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
    300     logs = logs or {}
    301     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 302       callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
    303 
    304   def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
   1711 
   1712     if self.histogram_freq and epoch % self.histogram_freq == 0:
-> 1713       self._log_weights(epoch)
   1714 
   1715     if self.embeddings_freq and epoch % self.embeddings_freq == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/callbacks.py in _log_weights(self, epoch)
   1802           with ops.init_scope():
   1803             weight = K.get_value(weight)
-> 1804           summary_ops_v2.histogram(weight_name, weight, step=epoch)
   1805           if self.write_images:
   1806             self._log_weight_as_image(weight, weight_name, epoch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/summary_ops_v2.py in histogram(name, tensor, family, step)
    821         name=scope)
    822 
--> 823   return summary_writer_function(name, tensor, function, family=family)
    824 
    825 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/summary_ops_v2.py in summary_writer_function(name, tensor, function, family)
    750   with ops.device("cpu:0"):
    751     op = smart_cond.smart_cond(
--> 752         should_record_summaries(), record, _nothing, name="")
    753     if not context.executing_eagerly():
    754       ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys._SUMMARY_COLLECTION, op)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/smart_cond.py in smart_cond(pred, true_fn, false_fn, name)
     52   if pred_value is not None:
     53     if pred_value:
---> 54       return true_fn()
     55     else:
     56       return false_fn()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/summary_ops_v2.py in record()
    743     with ops.name_scope(name_scope), summary_op_util.summary_scope(
    744         name, family, values=[tensor]) as (tag, scope):
--> 745       with ops.control_dependencies([function(tag, scope)]):
    746         return constant_op.constant(True)
    747 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/summary_ops_v2.py in function(tag, scope)
    819         tag,
    820         array_ops.identity(tensor),
--> 821         name=scope)
    822 
    823   return summary_writer_function(name, tensor, function, family=family)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_summary_ops.py in write_histogram_summary(writer, step, tag, values, name)
    467       try:
    468         return write_histogram_summary_eager_fallback(
--> 469             writer, step, tag, values, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
    470       except _core._SymbolicException:
    471         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_summary_ops.py in write_histogram_summary_eager_fallback(writer, step, tag, values, name, ctx)
    488   _attrs = ("T", _attr_T)
    489   _result = _execute.execute(b"WriteHistogramSummary", 0, inputs=_inputs_flat,
--> 490                              attrs=_attrs, ctx=ctx, name=name)
    491   _result = None
    492   return _result

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)
```

If anyone has any ideas on where to look to try and troubleshoot this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a point of doing this operation in the Network, and not before as preprocessing? I'm trying to understand your usecase to adapt my possible answer. I suspect that no weight are registered for those handcrafted operations, so the gradient can not be computed, hence the nan loss.

Comment: Main reason is to ensure that the inputs are calculated consistently between training, and inference. By keeping it in the network I can ensure that the inputs are always treated the exact same. There is also a speed component to it as well where if it can all be in the same execution, rather than multiple steps (inference batches are typically up to 300 samples, so would be ideal to be on GPU)

As for the weights, I also did try and use the `trainable=False` on each of the steps, and still got the same nan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest abstracting `handcrafted` as a separate model:

```
def __init__(self, ...):
    self.handcrafted = create_handcrafted()
    ....

def create_handcrafted(self):
    inp = Input((None, None, 3))
    _red = inp[:, :, :, 0]
    _green = inp[:, :, :, 1]
    _blue = inp[:, :, :, 2]
    handcrafted_channel_a = _red + _green
    handcrafted_channel_b = _green - _blue
    handcrafted_channels = KL.concatenate([handcrafted_channel_a, handcrafted_channel_b], axis=-1)
    return Model(inputs=[inp], outputs=[handcrafted_channels])

....
```

To then make this a part of the main model:

```
input_tensor = KL.Input(shape=input_image, name="input")
handcrafted_channels = self.handcrafted(input_tensor)
# Proceed as before
```

Comment: This is very interesting, will give it a go tomorrow